# Android deep linking -Using Branch.io link is not opened in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I am creating a branch link using websdk.
the following are the link properties from websdk:

```
var sampleParams = {
        tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ],
        channel: 'sample app',
        feature: 'share',
        stage: 'created link',
        type: 1,
        data: {
            mydata: 'bar',
            job_public:'https://onblickqa1.azurewebsites.net/Job/JobDetails?jobId=586e7f0dc99b2c0caccdae7d',

            '$desktop_url': 'https://onblickqa1.azurewebsites.net/Job/JobDetails?jobId=586e7f0dc99b2c0caccdae7d',
            '$og_title': 'Branch Metrics',
            '$og_description': 'Branch Metrics',
            '$og_image_url': 'http://branch.io/img/logo_icon_white.png'
        }
    };
```

and using the above generating the short url, the url from branch is like https://nc6e.test-app.link/BUy4NMpRGz
Now I am sharing this link via email. When I click on the above link in android, app is not able to detect this link. It is always redirecting to the Playstore url.

Android Manifest:

```
  <activity android:name=".activities.DeepLinkingActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="mvppdmo" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.auto_link_path"
            android:value="job_public" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.auto_link_request_code"
            android:value="@integer/AutoDeeplinkRequestCode" />
    </activity>
```

Branch Dashboard settings are:

I have checked the '**I have an Android app**' and '**Enable App Links**'
 **Uri schema: mvppdmo://**
 and gave the SHA1

Note: I am using the same branch test key in the web and android.

Can anybody tell me what the issue is?

Logcat report:

```
  I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW    dat=https://nc6e.test-app.link/... flg=0x14002000    cmp=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity (has extras)} from uid 10054 on display 0

  I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://nc6e.test-app.link/nX2d5p9pIz?__branch_flow_type=chrome_deepview&__branch_flow_id=345908912462718295' was   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image   'http://branch.io/img/logo_icon_white.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.", source: https://nc6e.test-app.link/nX2d5p9pIz?__branch_flow_type=chrome_deepview&__branch_flow_id=345908912462718295 (0)
```

Comment: Remove `android:host="open"`

Comment: No use. I am still redirect to the play store.

Comment: Can you extract a logcat to see what intents/urls are being used?

Comment: did you try  `android:autoVerify="true"`?

Comment: @kishorejethava I did but no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad I could help you directly through our support channel, Chaitu. For others, the issue came down to Chaitu's links pointing to a different package name than the app he was trying to launch. :)